# 2 col layout with borders collapses when zooming out with browser

Tags: html, css, layout, border

I have a 2 column layout, which structured something like this:

html structure:

```
#container
  #content
  #side-a
  .janitor
```

css:

```
#container{ width: 501px; }
#content { 
  float: left; 
  width: 300px;  
  border-right: 1px solid black;
}
#side-a{
  float: right;
  width: 200px;
}
.janitor {clear: both; }
```

When there is no border everything is fine, but when I add it, layout collapses on zooming out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because the border width is added to the content width you specified.

`#content` is 300px, `#side-a` is 200px - that's 500px altogether. `#container` is 501px. Without border's, you've 1px still left, BUT...

Adding a border, even 1px, makes `#content` 300px + 2px wide, `#side-a` 200px + 2px wide. I'm surprised it doesn't collapse when zoomed in.

You can fix this by using:

```
box-sizing: border-box;
```

(with appropriate vendor prefixes).

Comment: he's only got a border-right, so his css theoretically indeed adds up to 501px.

Comment: @Eamon: my reading skills are failing. Would you believe I totally missed the border declaration? o_O

Comment: It doesn't really matter: the extra pixel you introduce is apparently, in this instance (and I'd venture pretty much *always*), enough to overcome any inaccuracy.  So even if your motivation was a little confused the solution is fairly robust :-).

Answer (score 3):

**Ideal solution:** Don't use floats for this type of column layout.  You're using a fixed-size container of 501px anyhow; so there's no need for dynamic floating: just specify the positions explicitly - that is, assuming the height is well defined.  Alternately - yeah, really - use a table (or css's display: table if you like semantic purity) which implements columns in a natural way.

As to the specifics of your question: you have 1px of border and 200px+300px of content, which would *seem* to add up to 501px - i.e., it *should* fit indeed.  However, browsers cannot compute widths in arbitrary precision; they're rounding to some internal precision - and particularly when zoomed, that precision may well be related to device pixels, not CSS pixels: and if rounding introduces a bit of jitter, the sum of 1+200+300 may well be a little more or a little less than 501, and therefore cause the layout to unexpectedly no longer fit into the 501px container.  This is why you should probably never use this style of CSS coding - it's extremely device and browser specific and may break without warning due to small changes.  I'm willing to bet your layout doesn't break when zoomed in in all browsers...

Comment: +1. Seeing that I had missed the border declaration, the explanation you provide about how browsers are unable to correctly calculate pixel-perfect widths turns out to be the correct answer :D.